# ASP.NET Control For displaying a listing of data columns

Tags: asp.net, controls

Just wanted to see what is the best control to display a listing of about 5 columns (from a table) --I am thinking of a repeater control as far as being a light weight control -- Is this the right choice, or are there any better.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 on repeater. Most customizable / lightweight / whatever.. than datagrid or any other controls.

Comment: If you want total control over the layout of your data, Repeater is the way to go.  If you want a lot of built-in functionality, I'd still go with GridView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want full control over the markup Repeater is a good choice; the ASP.NET ListView is also a good choice, as the ListView gives you full control too.  Both give you access to template the entire control; the ListView allows for a little more control I think.  You can't go wrong with either.

It depends what you mean by light weight, whether you mean light on HTML output or light weight as in simplicity.

And there is explicit right choice; you really can't go wrong with most of the data binding controls, as long as it gives you the functionality you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few viable options:

A `Repeater` gives you basically no shiny features, but it's lightweight and you are in total control of the rendered output.

A `GridView` comes with a lot of built-in functionality like sorting, paging etc. Although you get little to none control of the output.

A `ListView` gives you all the power of the `GridView`, but you control all rendered output, just like the `Repeater`. It's basically the best of two worlds!

Although in your case, if your only intent is to view some data in a table, a repeater is probably the simplest and lightest option.

**Update**

I just thought of a fourth, fairly controversial way of doing this. I've never actually encountered this in the real world, so I'll include it for reference, and fun & giggles!

This code snippet assumes that you have a property on your page, containing your list of items, that is at least `protected`

```
<table>
    <% foreach(var item in MyListOfItems) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: item.SomeProperty %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```